How can I test an Angular component property value updated by observable callback before finalize() is called?
I have a component property that is updated in the next method of an observable I subscribe to that represents the upload progress of an http event. When writing unit tests for this method, I want to write a test that checks that the property is updated when subscribing to the http event.
The test I have written is:
it('Should display progress bar', async () => {
    mockFileTransferService.uploadQuarantineFile.and.returnValue(
      of(
        {
          body: ['blodId1'],
          type: 1,
          total: 50,
          loaded: 100,
        },
        {
          body: ['blodId1'],
          type: 1,
          total: 100,
          loaded: 100,
        })
    );
    component.onUpload();
    expect(component.uploadProgress).toBe(NumberConstant.FIFTY);
  });

The component's onUpload() method:
 onUpload() {
    const upload$ = this.fileTransferService.uploadQuarantineFile(this.formData)
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => this.reset())
      );
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
    this.subscription.add(upload$.subscribe((e: any) => {
      if (e.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress && e.total) {
        this.uploadProgress = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * NumberConstant.ONE_HUNDRED);
      }
      if (e.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
        this.messageBarService.openMessageBar(
          MessageBarStatesEnum.success,
          'File Uploaded successfully.',
          ''
        );
      }
    }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      this.error = true;
      this.errorMessage = error.message;
      this.trackingService.logTrace(error.message);
    }));
  }

My unit test is failing for the following reason: Expected 0 to be 50.
It appears that the finalize() method is being called before I can test the component's uploadProgress property because this.reset called by the finalize() method sets uploadProgress to 0.

Writing async tests could be quite tricky,
To understand why you have the issue, it arises from the async behaviour of your uploadQuarantineFile method, when the observable emits events and how your finalize() operator works. If you look closely finalize() is called when the observable completes, it runs before your test assertion, resetting the uploadProgress to 0.
I would encourage you when doing tests you can use fakeAsync and tick especially when doing asynchronous calls, as jasmine can be quite tricky with async.
To avoid this, I have modified your code to use them, I hope it helps.
For docs on both see: faskAsync and tick
Changed the func upload
import { HttpEventType, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

onUpload() {
  const upload$ = this.fileTransferService.uploadQuarantineFile(this.formData).pipe(
    finalize(() => this.reset())
  );

  const observer = {
    next: (event: HttpEvent<string[]>) => {
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress && event.total) {
        this.uploadProgress = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * NumberConstant.ONE_HUNDRED);
      }
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
        this.messageBarService.openMessageBar(
          MessageBarStatesEnum.success,
          'File Uploaded successfully.',
          ''
        );
      }
    },
    error: (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      this.error = true;
      this.errorMessage = error.message;
      this.trackingService.logTrace(error.message);
    }
  };

  this.subscription.add(upload$.subscribe(observer));
}

import { fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpEventType } from '@angular/common/http';

describe('UploadComponent', () => {
  let component: UploadComponent;
  let mockFileTransferService: jasmine.SpyObj<FileTransferService>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockFileTransferService = jasmine.createSpyObj('FileTransferService', ['uploadQuarantineFile']);
    component = new UploadComponent(mockFileTransferService);
  });

  it('Should update progress and display success message', fakeAsync(() => {
    const mockUploadEvents = [
      { type: HttpEventType.UploadProgress, loaded: 50, total: 100 },
      { type: HttpEventType.UploadProgress, loaded: 100, total: 100 },
      { type: HttpEventType.Response, body: ['blobId1'] }
    ];

    mockFileTransferService.uploadQuarantineFile.and.returnValue(of(...mockUploadEvents));

    spyOn(component, 'reset');
    spyOn(component.messageBarService, 'openMessageBar');

    component.onUpload();

    tick();
    expect(component.uploadProgress).toBe(50);

    tick(); 
    expect(component.uploadProgress).toBe(100);

    tick(); 
    expect(component.messageBarService.openMessageBar).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      MessageBarStatesEnum.success,
      'File Uploaded successfully.',
      ''
    );

    tick(); 
    expect(component.reset).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
});


Derek, I have implemented the method as your provided and I am now experiencing that both assertions are failing as uploadProgress is still set to 0 at each expect, which I confirmed by logging the value before each expect statement.

apologies I forgot tick at the last part you can also check if your method is called   spyOn(component, 'reset').and.callThrough();

Despite adding the changes you made to your edit, I'm still receiving the abovementioned failed assertions.

wow strange, i have modified your code i don't know how you implement your next func, so i tried to implement mine, changed a few things let see us what happens. I have uploaded a new code i hope it helps @Rick
